# The type RowMapper is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <User>

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

The type RowMapper is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

```
 `private static final class UserMapper implements RowMapper<User>{
     public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

           User user = new User();
           return user;
 }`
```

Comment: what do you mean? It is generic and in your example the type is User. Inside the mapRow you ll have to extract the details from the ResultSet yourself

Answer (score 1):

In current versions of Spring, `RowMapper` is a generic type:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html

But in early versions, it wasn't:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.0.0/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html

Check that you are using a version of Spring JDBC that is compatible with the code that you have written.  (Or if you need to use an old version of Spring, modify your code to be compatible with it.)

---

It appears that the API changed in Spring 3.0.0